# regex find first occurance beginning from end of the line

Tags: python, regex

I have this string

```
test = "total abc total foo total anything here total\ntotal total\ntotal\nstart\notal abc total foo total anything here total\notal abc total foo total anything here total\nstart\notal abc total foo total anything here total\n"
```

How would I go on about matching from the last occurance of `start` to the end of the line?
I tried [to do this](https://regex101.com/r/kxhgPx/1) with a negative lookahead but I would always get the first occurance:
`(?!$)\\nstart[\s\S]*?$`
Expecting match to be characters: 164-219

Comment: Since your text contains whitespace, could you please provide the code together with the exact string literal that you have a problem with?

Comment: Please also try `(?ms)^start$(?!.*^start$).*` ([demo on a plain text](https://regex101.com/r/cfdJ7e/1))

Comment: @user56700 See my first comment. I believe OP posted the string literal as literal text.

Comment: Thanks! Your expression works as expected would you care to explain it?

Comment: You can't just [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) [`.*\n(start.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/pNds7S/1) using `re.DOTALL` can you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
(?ms)^start$(?!.*^start$).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cfdJ7e/1).

*Details*:

- `(?ms)` - the `.` matches newlines now and the `^` / `$` anchors now match start/end of any line respectively
- `^` - start of a line
- `start` - a fixed word
- `$` - end of a line
- `(?!.*^start$)`  - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are any zero or more chars as many as possible followed with `start` as a whole line
- `.*` - the rest of the string.